# How to parse and calculate the elapsed seconds in a date stamp with this format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

Given a string like this:

`2020-04-09T13:15:52.838Z - 2020-04-09T13:16:09.704Z`

What is the correct way to calculate the amount of elapsed seconds? So far I tried this:

```
s = '2021-03-09T13:15:52.838Z - 2021-03-09T13:16:09.704Z'.split(' - ')

datetime.strptime(s[0], "%Y-%m-%d").date() - datetime.strptime(s[1],"%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

However, I am not sure how to extract the seconds and calculate the elapsed time between the two time stamps. Any idea of how to get the elapsed time in seconds?

Comment: "I am not sure how to extract the seconds" You seem to have already found datetime and strptime. What problem do you have extending the parse format to include hours:minutes:seconds.micro?

Comment: That's correct @MisterMiyagi

Comment: *What* is correct? The [documentation of datetime/strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) covers both date and time formats the same. How are you stuck with just the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to convert each string into a datetime (here using [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and using a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) that matches the format of your time strings) and then subtract one from the other to get a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#timedelta-objects) object.  Then you can call the [total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method on the timedelta object. Here's one way you might do it:

```
import datetime

s = '2021-03-09T13:15:52.838Z - 2021-03-09T13:16:09.704Z'.split(' - ')

first_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(s[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
second_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(s[1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

time_delta = second_time - first_time

print(time_delta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, where did you get this format: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`?

Comment: I added links in the answer to the documentation. But basically, I made it up by looking at the way your date strings are formatted and substituting in the codes that you find here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior  Starts with a four digit year?  "%Y"  Then a dash?  "%Y-" Then a two-digit month? "%Y-%m" and so on.  The dashes, colons, T, and Z and spaces and whatever else you might find can just be their literal selves. (The "Z" actually means the times are UTC timezone, but that's beyond the scope of this answer and I'm ignoring it for simplicity..)